# How to @Autowire to different component implementation on environment variable condition in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an interface and implementation classes in Spring Boot something like this,

```
public interface Foo {
   String foo();
}

//
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public LocalFooImpl implements Foo {
   String foo() {
     return "I am local. No network required.";
   }
}

//
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public RemoteFooImpl implements Foo {
   String foo() {
      return "I am remote. A lot of network required.";
   }
}
```

I am going to use the it in the RestController. I am thinking something like below. Please correct me if I am wrong, I am very new to Spring Boot.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {

   @Autowired
   private Foo myFoo;
}
```

I am thinking that, when I am running this controller in the remote environment it will use the `RemoteFooImpl` instance, but for local development it will use the `LocalFooImpl`. In the remote deployment, I am going to put an environment variable, something like `IS_REMOTE=1`. So when the application detects `IS_REMOTE` environment variable exists it will use `RemoteFooImpl`. But in the local or build server, it will use the `LocalFooImpl`.

How do I achieve that? Is there a Spring annotation I can use, or is there a Factory pattern that I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring profiles are exactly what you are looking for. You can annotate both of your components with `@Profile` in the following way:

```java
@Profile("remote")
@Component
public RemoteFooImpl implements Foo {
   String foo() {
      return "I am remote. A lot of network required.";
   }
}
```

```java
@Profile("!remote")// or @Profile("local")
@Component
public LocalFooImpl implements Foo {
   String foo() {
     return "I am local. No network required.";
   }
}
```

Then, set an active profile using the property below:

```
spring.profiles.active=remote
```

For more details check [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles).

Comment: Awesome! How do I use the `RemoteFooImpl` on more than 1 profile, e.g. `prod` and `stg`? Do I stack 2 `@Profile` lines?

Comment: For multiple profiles use this:`@Profile({"prod", "stg"})`